# Mysql real escape string not working for textarea apostrophe on insert getting syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, apostrophe, mysql-real-escape-string

Whenever I'm trying to insert data that has an apostrophe in it, I receive a

> mysql syntax error

Example text in textarea : `I'm an alien` will throw a syntax error when I try to insert in the database. I'm using `real_escape_string` and still is not working.

**query snippet**

```
$text=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($_POST['text']))));
```

**markup**

```
<textarea name='text' placeholder="Type your message here... " value=''></textarea>
```

Comment: How does your sql script look like? Are you using parameterized query?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: looks something like this : $updateText = "UPDATE table SET text='$text' WHERE user='$id'";

Comment: Using parameterized query should resolve this issue. Or may be you can replace single quote with double quote before appending it to the query.

Comment: While parametrized queries are the better solution, `mysqli_real_escape_string` should prevent apostrophes from causing problems. What do you see if you `echo $updateText`?

Comment: `mysql syntax error` is not an error message that comes from MySQL. What is the full error message that comes from `mysqli_error($db)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

Just use parameterized queries. Then you don't have to do any escaping, and apostrophes will never be a problem.

It's really easy:

```
$text=trim($_POST['text']);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE table SET text=? WHERE user=?");
$stmt->execute([$text, $id]);
```

Using stripslashes() and striptags() should be unnecessary, too.

You can also do prepared statements with parameters with Mysqli. But you should use PDO.

Comment: He's using mysqli, not PDO.

Comment: @Barmar: He actually has the right concept but I had to look for a mysqli version of his answer so I will post it.

Comment: @Barmar, I've decided I'm going to encourage people to use PDO over Mysqli. The only reason I'd support using Mysqli is that it's easier to convert legacy PHP code that used ext/mysql.

Comment: I also prefer PDO over mysqli. But answers are not the appropriate place for software recommendations,they should be in comments.

Comment: And if you're going to recommend PDO prepared queries, use named placeholders instead of `?`

Comment: @Barmar, PDO supports both named and positional placeholders. In this example, it's simpler to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use parameterized queries. This did the tricK:

```
 //get variables
 $id = $_POST['id'];
 $text=trim($_POST['text']);

 $sqlText= "UPDATE table SET text=? WHERE user=?";
 $updateText = $db->prepare($sqlText);
 $updateText->bind_param('si',$text, $id);
 $updateText->execute();
```